# VBA Addin to Insert Images in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have built a custom menu to insert images into MS Word. Each sub-menu item is linked to a macro that inserts the image. When I run the macro individually, it inserts the correct image. However, when I click the respective item from the addin menu, it always inserts the first image. so, that tells me that there is an issue with the code in my addin menu.

The code below creates the addin menu:

```
    Set MenuObject = Application.CommandBars(1). _
                Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, _
                Before:=10, _
                Temporary:=True)
    MenuObject.Caption = "Images"

    Set MenuItem = MenuObject.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
    MenuItem.Caption = "set 1"

    Set SubMenuItem = MenuItem.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    SubMenuItem.Caption = "image name 1"
    SubMenuItem.OnAction = "macro_1"

    Set SubMenuItem = MenuItem.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    SubMenuItem.Caption = "image name 2"
    SubMenuItem.OnAction = "macro_2"


    Set SubMenuItem = MenuItem.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
    SubMenuItem.Caption = "image name 3"
    SubMenuItem.OnAction = "macro_3"
```

The macro code that insert the images:

```
    Sub macro_1()
    Dim objTbl As Table
    Dim rg As Range
    With ActiveDocument
    Set objTbl = .Tables(1)
    Set rg = objTbl.Cell(Row:=nRow, Column:=1).Range
    .InlineShapes.AddPicture _
    FileName:="\\shared drive path\image_1.PNG", Range:=rg
    End With
    End Sub
```

I have separate sub's to insert the other images and is identical to the above, except for the PNG's are different. (image_2.PNG, image_3.PNG)

When running the macro's individually they work fine. When I click the menu items linked to the macro's, it always inserts "Image_1" PNG. Cannot seems to figure out why!

Comment: Is your add-in for a non-ribbon version of Word?

Comment: @TimothyRylatt It is for a Ribbon version.

Comment: Where is `nRow` incremented/modified? Please, try placing brake lines (click in their first code line and press `F9`) on all three called macros and then run the code line by line pressing `F8` and see what's happening. Do you delete the controls in discussion and recreate them, from time to time? If not, maybe they have been wrongly created (by copying the first one code) and all of them call the same `Sub`...

Comment: Although the `CommandBars` object still works it was deprecated some time ago. I suggest that you add ribbon functionality to your code instead. There are some tools available that can help you if you find xml difficult.

Comment: @FaneDuru - nRow was something i had when the table had multiple rows. I now just have the one cell so I have replaced it with the numeral 1. I tried deleting the control and recreating, still does not work

Comment: @TimothyRylatt - do you have any resources or examples to share on how to make this compatible to the ribbon?

Comment: Most of the online resources are for Excel, though that doesn't matter as the principles are the same. [Ron de Bruin](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win003.htm) has some good examples. You could also use your favourite search engine to look up ribbonx. There is also a [Ribbon Creator tool](https://ribboncreator2021.de/en/)

Comment: @TimothyRylatt - thank you for the alternatives. But any ideas on why the current setup isn't working ?

Comment: See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/16772-4-digital-images-1-page.html?highlight=addpics